# Angular. Размещение backend НЕ в интернет

Tags: сеть, веб-сервер, asp.net-web-api, angular, localhost

Заранее извиняюсь, за, возможно глупый вопрос, первый раз этим занимаюсь.
Суть в следующем. Есть фронт на Angular и бек на ASP Web API.
И фронт и бек развернуты на одном IIS сервере. Возможно ли только фронт выкинуть в интернет и обращаться к беку по внитрисетевому адресу, т.е. ip сервера:порт?

Comment: Нет, не возможно.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Разрешите еще один вопрос. Тогда и на фронт и на бек нужны SSL сертификаты?

Comment: Если сервер с которого загружается фронт и сервер на котором работает бэк доступны с разных доменных имён, то да. Если с одного, то нет.

Comment: Т.е. если повесить на один адрес, но разные порты, то можно обойтись и одним сертификатом?

Comment: Зачем на разные порты? Очень хочется с Same Origin Policy намучиться?

Comment: Мучиться совсем не хочется. Просто не совсем понимаю тогда Ваше высказывание "Если с одного, то нет". Не могли бы чуть пояснить? Может ссылка есть?

Comment: Фронтенд - это программа, состоящая из разметки, стилей и javascript-кода, загружающаяся с сервера по протоколу http в бразуер клиента и работающая там. Фронтенд чаще всего отправляет http-запросы на тот же сервер, откуда загрузился. А бэкенд - это программа выполняющаяся на сервере и отвечающая на эти запросы. То есть их не обязательно разность на разные сервера, адреса или порты.